# Get data from a join of two tables yii2

Tags: join, yii2

I'm new to yii2 and trying to make a dropdown in yii2, but i can't get the data in a correct way from the tables. This are persona and docente and they are related through id_persona. The fields i need are docente.id_docente and persona.nombre and i get them by making a join:

```
 $personas = Persona::find()->with('docentes')->all();
```

then i map the data i need for the dropdown:

```
$data = ArrayHelper::map($personas, 'docente.id_docente','nombre');
```

I get the error the following error:

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\Persona::docente
```

**what am i doing wrong?**

When i do a var_dump($personas) i get:

```
array (size=4)
   0 => 
    object(app\models\Persona)[71]
      private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=15)
          'id_persona' => int 15
          'nombre' => string 'prueba' (length=6)
          'apellido' => string 'prueba' (length=6)
          ...
   1 => 
    object(app\models\Persona)[90]
      private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=15)
          'id_persona' => int 16
          'nombre' => string 'sebastian' (length=9)
          'apellido' => string 'carreras' (length=8) 
          ...
```

The fields from table docente are not in there, i don't understand...

Model persona:

```
/**
* @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
*/
public function getAlumnos()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Alumno::className(), ['id_persona' =>'id_persona']);
}

/**
* @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
*/
public function getDocentes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Docente::className(),['id_persona'=>'id_persona']);
}
```

model docente

```
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIdPersona()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Persona::className(), ['id_persona' => 'id_persona']);
}
```

Comment: can you show us your model?

Comment: show your Persona and Docente model

Comment: do you need the complete model or just that? i created them with the gii tool